# Windows Scripting Host popup - on top of other windows

Tags: javascript, windows, wsh

I have this simple Windows JavaScript which will popup a reminder every 30 minutes for 10 seconds. How do I make the popup appear on the top of all other windows?

```
var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
while(1) {
    var value = wshShell.Popup("Reminder text", 10, "Reminder", 0x1);
    if (value == 2) { // Cancel button pressed
        break;  
    }

    WScript.sleep(30 * 60 * 1000); // Every 30 minutes
}

WScript.Echo("Exiting timer!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from [Clackwell’s Weblog](https://toodifficult.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/always-stay-on-top-for-wscriptshellpopup/)

WScript.Shell.Popup has an undocumented value for the nType parameter which causes the resulting dialogs/popups to “stay on top” / in foreground, meaning that they cannot be hidden by other windows or dialogs: 4096.

```
JScript example:

WScript.CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”).Popup(“Message”, 0, “Title”, 4096);

VBScript example:

WScript.CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”).Popup “Message”, 0, “Title”, 4096
```

Also documented in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx)